# How to properly query a Firebase list in AngularFire2?

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, observable, angularfire2, querying

I'm developing an Angular2 application with Firebase as a backend. On a subpage I want to display some tasks for a given week which is specified by a route parameter.

I'm using a `BehaviorSubject` as a parameter to the AngularFire2 query the following way:

```
export class PrepareComponent implements OnInit {

    private routeSub: any;
    weekId = '';

    private weekSubject: BehaviorSubject<any> = new BehaviorSubject('weekId');

    taskTemplates$: FirebaseListObservable<TaskTemplate[]>;

    constructor(private route: ActivatedRoute,
                private router: Router,
                private angularFire: AngularFire) {

        // this.taskTemplates$ = angularFire.database.list("/taskTemplates");
```

Here is the Firebase query:

```
        this.taskTemplates$ = angularFire.database.list("/taskTemplates", {
            query: {
                equalTo: this.weekSubject
            }
        });
    }

    ngOnInit() {
        this.routeSub = this.route.params.map(
            (params: Params) => this.weekId = params[ 'weekid' ]
        ).subscribe(
            weekId => this.weekSubject.next(weekId)
        );
    }

    ngOnDestroy() {
        this.routeSub.unsubscribe();
    }
}
```

Unfortunately, the Firebase `taskTemplates$` observable is not returning any data for the given weekId.

I assumed that once the `weekId` will be set by querying the route parameters, the list would get it as a query parameter and return the data which has: `{ weekId: actualWeekId, ...}`.

**EDIT** Added an example of data stored in Firebase:

```
  {
   "-Kc_E0U4UOl9PPtxpzCM" : {
   "description" : "asdfasdf",
   "weekId" : "99f2"
  },
  "-Kc_E3wv3fhpUt56sM4u" : {
    "description" : "another task",
    "weekId" : "99f2"
  }
}
```

So what I want to do is to get all records for a given `weekId`

Comment: Could you include a representation of your data in the question, too?

Comment: @cartant I added example data to the question. Thanks for helping!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The core problem appears to be the `query` that's specified when the list observable is created.

Given the structure of the data, it seems that `orderByChild` is what should be used, as you appear to be wanting to select the entries that have a particular `weekId`.

The query in the question's code will be looking for entries that have keys equal to the `weekid` obtained from the activated route. However, the keys are push keys, like `-Kc_E0U4UOl9PPtxpzCM`.

You can also simplify the code somewhat by composing the query observable directly from the activated route. Something like this should do what you want:

```ts
export class PrepareComponent implements OnInit {

  taskTemplates$: FirebaseListObservable<TaskTemplate[]>;

  constructor(
    private route: ActivatedRoute,
    private router: Router,
    private angularFire: AngularFire
  ) {}

  ngOnInit() {
    this.taskTemplates$ = this.angularFire.database.list("/taskTemplates", {
      query: {
        orderByChild: 'weekId',
        equalTo: this.route.params.map((params: Params) => params['weekid'])
      }
    });
  }
}
```

If you are using `orderByChild` you will likely see a console warning about an index - if you've not already created one. You need to use the security rules to do that. It should be explained well enough in the documentation.

Comment: Great, it works now! I'm getting a warning to use the `.indexOn` because of performance considerations. Where do I have to specifiy this?

Comment: I've found it, its in the Firebase Rules section.

Answer (score 22):

If anyone is having a hard time like me nowadays, this might help you guys:

```
db.list('/items', ref => ref.orderByChild('size').equalTo('large'))
```

Please refer to 
    https://github.com/angular/angularfire2/blob/master/docs/rtdb/querying-lists.md

for more information!

Comment: The above is the solution for AngularFire2 version 5 and up!

Comment: plus 1 for providing the link too. Works like a charm. Just verified against Angular 6 and AngularFire2.